# get file (i.e. pdf) accessor username using vba

Tags: file, vba

I have an issue, I need to get the username of the person who is opening a certain pdf file. I found this code yesterday but it always gives me "runtime error 5" and when i debug it, it will highlight this line "MyLastUser = MyMatches(0)".

Please help me to solve this error or do you have any other code than this.

and just to inform you, I'm not really familiar with vba.

Thank you.

Code as seen below:-

> ```
> Sub GetLastUser()
>     Dim MyFile As String            ' File name
>     Dim MyRegExp As Object
>     Dim MyLastUser                  ' last user name
>     Dim LastUserLen As Integer      ' character 5 name length
>     Dim FileString As String        ' file converted to a string in memory
>     Dim MyMatches As Variant        ' RegExp array of matches (should only be 1)
>     Dim MyLastSaved As String       ' "Last saved by" from properties
>     '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     ChDrive "L:\"
>     ChDir "L:\07 KNOWLEDGE SHARING\IDCAS test"
>     MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
>     If MyFile = "False" Then End
>     '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     '- PUT THE FILE INTO MEMORY AND CLOSE IT
>     Open MyFile For Binary Access Read Shared As #1
>         FileString = Space(LOF(1))
>         Get 1, 1, FileString
>     Close #1
>     '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     '- SET UP A REGULAR EXPRESSION
>     Set MyRegExp = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")
>     With MyRegExp
>         .Global = True
>         .Pattern = "\\\x00p\x00.\x00\x00.{50}"      ' 57 characters should be enough
>         Set MyMatches = .Execute(FileString)        ' zero based array
>         '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         '- DISPLAY RESULTS (should only be 1 match = Matches(0))
>         '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         '- check only 1
>      '   If MyMatches.Count <> 1 Then
>            ' MsgBox ("Found " & MyMatches.Count & " matches" & vbCr _
>             '        & "Only showing first one.")
>       '  End If
>         '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         '- exclude first 7 characters & trailing spaces
>         MyLastUser = MyMatches(0)                       ' 57 characters found
>         LastUserLen = Asc(Mid(MyLastUser, 5, 1))        ' length of name
>         MyLastUser = Mid(MyLastUser, 8, LastUserLen)    ' extract name
>         '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         '- Message
>         rsp = MsgBox(MyFile & vbCr & "Last user : " & MyLastUser)
>         '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>         FileString = ""
>     End With
>     '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> End Sub
> '========================================================================================
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`Environ$("username")` will return the current username

Comment: thanks but how do i put it in vba? n how do i tell vba which pdf file i want to check.

Comment: vba is not useable in a pdf. How is the pdf being opened? is it just straight through explorer? If so seems like you might have to actually set up a db backend and use javascript or action script which are supported by pdf. otherwise please explain further how this process is occuring?